# Select only specific cases from dataframe

Tags: r, select, dataframe

How can I select only the rows that are followed by the same value in a specific column?

i.e.
from this (using as a reference the values of the v1)

```
`v1 = c(1,1,2,3,1,2,4,1,1,2,3,4)
 v2 = seq(1:12)
 v3 = c(rep("blue", 4), rep("red", 4), rep("green", 4))
 df<- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
 df`

> df
   v1 v2    v3
1   1  1  blue
2   1  2  blue
3   2  3  blue
4   3  4  blue
5   1  5   red
6   2  6   red
7   4  7   red
8   1  8   red
9   1  9 green
10  2 10 green
11  3 11 green
12  4 12 green
```

to this; where only the cases 1 and 8, that are followed by cases where value for v1 is also 1 are saved

```
  v1 v2   v3
1  1  1 blue
8  1  8  red
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the indices of interest with which, and then extract the rows of interest from the dataframe.

```
indices <- which(df$v1[1:(nrow(df)-1)]==df$v1[2:nrow(df)])
df.new <- df[indices,]
```

Comment: The @Christopher Brown option is faster than the akrun one. My data frame has more than 1.600.000 cases, the akrun option takes between 15' and 20'. The second one only few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to get the run-length type id, use that as grouping variable, and `if` the nrow is greater than 1 (`.N >1`), select the first observation (`head(.SD, 1L)`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(.N>1) head(.SD, 1L) ,.(v1,rleid(v1))][,rleid:= NULL][]
#    v1 v2   v3
# 1:  1  1 blue
# 2:  1  8  red
```

NOTE: We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' with `setDT(df)`.

Comment: this is not a scalable solution to the question

Comment: @mtoto Can you explain what you meant?

Comment: I have edited his question, wasnt clear to me either at first. He wants to return rows that have the same value in the subsequent row of `v1`

Comment: @JoanSales I am the getting expected output as you showed in the result.  I don't really understand what you meant, but if this is not the one, please convey it clearly.

Comment: My R is not good enough to answer this, but it sounds like he wants a kind of "group by" on `v1`. Your answer does not give that, you merely pick out the appropriate rows manually.

Comment: @NamelessOne My second option is not manual, if you check it.  He clearly mentioned in the post about v1 as 1 and v2 as 1, 8.

Comment: His question is unclear because he is not an English first language speaker. But he refers to repeating values in `v1` which you can see in the data, that is why he singles out 1 and 8 as the answer in this particular case. Your answer does not give the solution he wants, it only gives the desired output for this one data set.

Comment: @NamelessOne  You can check once more in my updated answer

Comment: I don't understand your answer now, since my R is too rusty. But it looks better. I'll remove my downvote.